# foundation accordion build with javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I want to build a foundation accordion element using a for loop.
A basic example of accoordion from Foundation doc looks like this:

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>

    <!-- Accordion tab title -->
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>    
    <!-- Accordion tab content -->
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
     <p>Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
     <a href="#">Nowhere to Go</a>
    </div>

  </li>
  <!-- ... -->

</ul>
```

Each `<li>` element of my listing is coming from a json file and added using a for loop like this:

```
var listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    listing.className = 'accordion-item';
```

which gives me the `<li class="accordion-item"` term correctly, but how do I add the `data-accordion-item` term?

Comment: This should do it listing.setAttribute('data-accordion-item', "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, thanks to [iSZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3713790/isz). 
 `listing.setAttribute('data-accordion-item', "");` did the trick.